# How do I create a query to trace connectivity from a given record?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have a table of connected nodes representing a map which have their own respective from and to sections specifying how they are connected:

> from - NODENUMBER1 - to - from - NODENUMBER2 - to

I am running some testing to try to remove sections off of this map and I would like to pick a single node to remove all nodes downstream of it.

I would like to know how to accomplish this through a SQL query such as this pseudo-SQL:

```
select A.nodes from node_table A, node_table B
where A.to_section = B.from_section
and **A.starting_node = NODENUMBER_X**;
```

So by setting NODENUMBER_X, the query would then produce all nodes connected downstream of NODENUMBER_X.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not always great for efficiency, but it's one way to solve this kind of problem. Assuming node_table has a unique field node_id (int):

```
declare @start_node_id int, @loop_limit int, @loop_count int;

set @start_node_id = 1234;  -- Insert the node ID you want to start from.
set @loop_limit = 1000;     -- Set a limit on the number of loop iterations.
set @loop_count = 0;

create table #NODES_TO_DELETE(NODE_ID int);

-- Get first child nodes, directly linked to start node.
insert into #NODES_TO_DELETE(NODE_ID)
select A.NODE_ID
from node_table A inner join node_table B on B.from_section = A.to_section
where B.NODE_ID = @start_node_id;

-- If there are child nodes not yet in our temp table, continue loop.
WHILE EXISTS(select 1
    from node_table A inner join node_table B on B.from_section = A.to_section
    inner join #NODES_TO_DELETE D on B.NODE_ID = D.NODE_ID
    left join #NODES_TO_DELETE X on A.NODE_ID = X.NODE_ID
    where X.NODE_ID is null) and 
@loop_count < @loop_limit
BEGIN
    -- Add child nodes to temp table. Avoid duplicate IDs.
    insert into #NODES_TO_DELETE(NODE_ID)
    select distinct A.NODE_ID
    from node_table A inner join node_table B on B.from_section = A.to_section
    inner join #NODES_TO_DELETE D on B.NODE_ID = D.NODE_ID
    left join #NODES_TO_DELETE X on A.NODE_ID = X.NODE_ID
    where X.NODE_ID is null;

    -- Increment loop count.
    set @loop_count = @loop_count + 1;
END

IF @loop_count > @loop_limit
    print 'Loop limit exceeded.';   -- We've exceeded our loop limit. May not have all matches.
ELSE
    delete N    -- Delete all nodes inserted into our temp table.
    from node_table N
    inner join #NODES_TO_DELETE D on N.NODE_ID = D.NODE_ID;

drop table #NODES_TO_DELETE;
```